# Sed comand to rename folder name (parts contained between [])

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, rename

i've two questions :

1. First of all, how can i use the sed command to apply changes in folders not in filenames ?
   I tried thee easy command `sed -i -e 's/Temporada//g' f` but doesn't work.
2. I'm trying to use sed command to rename folder and filenames which contains at least three parts like this [xxxxx][yyyyy][zzzzz987], but i only want to erase which doesn't contains numbers. I'm pretty lost how to define it using regex, how to distinguish the [] parts and how to discriminate one which contains numbers.

**Example** :

*Origin*

Project - [Enterprise][Date.02022016][DBB XXXXX]

*Result*

Project - [Date.02022016]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add examples what you want to see. I think you want something like `mv dirTemporada dir` and `mv "[xxxxx][yyyy][zzzz666]" xxxxyyyyxxx` (when `[xxxxx][yyyy][zzzz666]` has numbers inside whatever part. And which files to skip. What to do with the file `[xxxxx][yyyy][zzzz666]andSomethingOutsideBrackets`

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command. There are at least two different `rename` implementations.

Comment: Example added to the post.

Comment: There are no folders in UNIX. You're probably thinking of directories. Read an intro to UNIX tutorial before you start writing scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that should sort it out (remember to back up your data before you test anything):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in Project*;
do      
        new=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/Project - \(\[.[^\[]*\]\)\(\[.[^\[]*\]\)\(\[.[^\[]*\]\)/Project - \2/')
        mv "$i" "$new"
done
```

First it takes all files/directories that start with "`Project`" in the current directory and applies the commands between `do` and `done` to each of the files:

- gets the file/dir name string (`$i`) and applies the required string modifications saving the new string in a new variable `$new`.
- Then it moves/renames the old file/dir (`$i`) to the new one (`$new`).

See the output:

```
xtd8865@darkstar:~/tmp/temp$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Enterprise][Date.01032015][DBB\ fda]
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Enterprise][Date.03032015][DBB\ dfada]
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Enterprise][Date.04032015][DBB\ afdad]
drwxr-xr-x 2 xtd8865 users 4096 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Enterprise][Date.3234223][DBB\ dafa]/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xtd8865 users  169 Feb  7 13:35 script.sh*
xtd8865@darkstar:~/tmp/temp$ ./script.sh 
Project - [Enterprise][Date.01032015][DBB fda]
Project - [Enterprise][Date.03032015][DBB dfada]
Project - [Enterprise][Date.04032015][DBB afdad]
Project - [Enterprise][Date.3234223][DBB dafa]
xtd8865@darkstar:~/tmp/temp$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Date.01032015]
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Date.03032015]
-rw-r--r-- 1 xtd8865 users    0 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Date.04032015]
drwxr-xr-x 2 xtd8865 users 4096 Feb  7 13:34 Project\ -\ [Date.3234223]/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xtd8865 users  169 Feb  7 13:35 script.sh*
```

As you can see, it'll rename files and directories.

The sed command itself uses sed's backreferencing capabilities. More information on backreferencing can be found e.g [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/).

Comment: Your unquoted use of the variable `"$i"` will wreak havoc with many real-world file names.

Comment: The backslashes in your output look weird, and don't match the OP's example.

Comment: In terms of backslashes - Copied the OP's desired output and there is one blank space surrounding the hyphen.

Comment: You still have a bare unquoted `echo $i` in the command substitution.

Comment: My copy of `ls` doesn't backslash spaces in file names; does yours?

Comment: Mine does. I guess we have different env variables or Coreutils versions

Comment: Amazing answer. Works perfect. Now i need to understand every parameter in the sed command.

Comment: You don't need all of those capture groups in the regexp, just the one you use in the replacement, nor do they need to be that complicated. All you really need is something like (untested) `sed 's/Project - \[\]*\]\(\[[^]]*\]\).*/Project - \1/'` You don't need the trailing semi-colons either.